# How to put a password on button click to open another activity?

Tags: android

I have button one in activity1 and i have also activity2 which i want to open if I click the button. However only users with the password can pass to activity2. I need to put a password on the button so that when the user clicks, it asks the password, when the passord is correct the user can open activity2  and if the password is wrong, a toast message shows. The password is same to all users. My question is, how do i implement  this password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show a dialog asking for password when the user clicks on the Button in Activity1, then based on the password entered by user you can go to the Activity2.

```
private void showPasswordDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder pswdDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity1.this);
        pswdDialog.setTitle("Enter Password");

        final EditText input = new EditText(Activity1.this);
        pswdDialog.setView(input);

        pswdDialog.setPositiveButton("Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                String password = input.getText().toString();
                if (password.equals("123456")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(Activity1.this, "Incorrect password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        pswdDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        pswdDialog.show();
    }
```